# Lilypond: vertical spacing between lyrics and staff

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to change my vertical spacing of my lilypond music score. But so far, without success. Probably I have been searching for the wrong key words in google and the lilypond manual (I am not a native English speaker).

My score contains staffs with 3 lyric lines and other staffs with only one lyric line. Normally lilypond grants the staffs with 3 lyric lines more space than the staffs with only 1 lyric line. This spacing depending on lyric lines is perfectly fine. I want it like this.

However, I am not satisfied as I would really like to add some more space between the lyric lines and the following staff line (looks way too full in my opinion). The only way I found so far is changing

```
system-system-spacing #'basic-distance = some_number\mm
```

which can add vertical space between staffs but leads to equidistant spacing between all staffs - no matter if containing 3 or only 1 lyric line.

I hope that the above explanation is comprehensible, in short:
How can I change the space between my (last) lyric line and the following staff?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nonstaff-unrelatedstaff-spacing`:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-unrelatedstaff-spacing.padding = #5
  }
}
```

You might also like to refrain from specifying distances in mm. Just omit the units and specify everything in staff spaces. That way the spacing will scale when you change the staff size.